# Kafka Streams: Can someone point me to a fully implemented java example of sending messages to a DLQ (Dead Letter Queue) topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an external dependency on another system in my streams app and would like to publish a message to DLQ kafka topic from within my streams app whenever a Deserialization/Producer/or any external/network exception happens, so that I can monitor that topic and reprocess records as needed. I can't seem to find a good example of doing this anywhere. The closest reference I found is https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#option-3-quarantine-corrupted-records-dead-letter-queue, but 1. It talks only about DeserializationExceptionHandler, what about other exception scenarios?  2. It doesn't demo the right way to configure/manage/close the associated KafkaProducer.

I would like to have try catch for the external dependency code and send the record(s) that cause exception to a dead letter queue topic. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the *processing* logic you could take this approach:

```java
someKStream 

    // the processing logic
    .mapValues(inputValue -> {
        // for each execution the below "return" could provide a different class than the previous run!
        // e.g. "return isFailedProcessing ? failValue : successValue;" 
        // where failValue and successValue have no related classes
        return someObject; // someObject class vary at runtime depending on your business
    }) // here you'll have KStream<whateverKeyClass, Object> -> yes, Object for the value!

    // you could have a different logic for choosing  
    // the target topic, below is just an example
    .to((k, v, recordContext) -> v instanceof failValueClass ?
            "dead-letter-topic" : "success-topic",
            // you could completelly ignore the "Produced" part 
            // and rely on spring-boot properties only, e.g. 
            // spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.key.serde=yourKeySerde
            // spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.value.serde=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
            Produced.with(yourKeySerde, 
                            // JsonSerde could be an instance configured as you need 
                            // (with type mappings or headers setting disabled, etc)
                            new JsonSerde<>()));
```

Your classes, though different and landing into different topics, will serialize as expected.

When not using `to()`, but instead one wants to continue with other processing, he could use `branch()` with splitting the logic based on the kafka-value class; the trick for `branch()` is to return `KStream<keyClass, ?>[]` in order to further allow one to cast to the appropriate class the individual items from `KStream<keyClass, ?>[]`.